# Seek function don´t work on flex videoPlayer after the video finish

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

The video seeks normally when first playing but when it finishes i can´t seek the video again. I used a listener to call a function after the event TimeEvent.COMPLETE occurs(video finishes). In the function i call the function player.seek(20) for example but it doesn´t work. The video keeps in the end of it. Have anyone faced this problem?

Answer (score 0):

what type of object are you attaching the listener event to? "Complete" works differently on different objects so you may have to catch the event sooner

Comment: I´m attachin a VideoPlayer object @j.steelman. This is how i´m doing it: `code` player.addEventListener(TimeEvent.CURRENT_TIME_CHANGE, player_currentTimeChangeHandler); I solved the problem now. When the video ends and the player_currentTimeChangeHandler function is called i reset the video source. It worked perfect. Now i can seek the video as usual. I don´t know if this is the better way but it worked. Thank you